# Redshift GetClusterCredentials IAM policy to require DbName

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam

How can I define an IAM policy to effectively require DbName?

What I'm trying to do is only allow GetClusterCredentials calls with a specified, whitelisted DbName.  The problem is the DbName argument is optional.  I am also specifying the DbUser resource so that I can refer to `${redshift:DbUser}` in an IAM policy condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the condition keys GetClusterCredentials supports is `redshift:DbName`, which can be used to restrict an IAM policy based on database name. For example, the following policy statement should deny the action if the DbName is not set to "test-db".

```
{
  "Sid": "GetClusterCredsStatement",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "redshift:GetClusterCredentials"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:123456789012:dbname:examplecluster/*"
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "redshift:DbName": "test-db"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was missing - I forgot that you can use redshift:DbName in a condition key, not just as a resource.  That also allows you to have an explicit DENY on `"Null": {"redshift:DbName": "true"}`